# Larger squares in a grid using nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, grid

I need some help getting my grid right. I've created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tyssen/pen/wvRmQpZ) which shows the issue.

With

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>
```

and

```
.parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: 410px;
}

.child {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child:nth-child(2),
.child:nth-child(4n) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 210px;
}
```

it's nearly right except for here:

[image]

where there shouldn't be a row of non-square boxes in between, it should always alternate between having a large square box on the right followed by one on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```css
.child:nth-child(6n+2),
.child:nth-child(6n+4) { }
```

```css
.parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: 410px;
}

.child {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child:nth-child(6n+2),
.child:nth-child(6n+4) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>
```

It's just a matter of working out the patterns, and then working out how to select them:

```
2,4 … 8, 10 … 14, 16 … 20, 22 … 26, 28 …
```